# What is the best way to sanitize a string with html tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, sanitize

I am building a Blog app in React with Quill and I want to know how to build it safely, avoiding xss attacks.

Comment: That's a question you should ask Google first. Then try something, write some code, and if you're stuck at some point, then we can help. But unfortunately this is not a tutorial writing service... [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Unless you're dangerously setting innerHTML you don't need to worry about it because react escapes html for you https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks

Comment: read about html5 content-security-policy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.